# Mock retrofit Observable error

Tags: android, unit-testing, mockito, rx-java, retrofit2

I am using Mockito to test a Presenter functions. I have built some Fake API Responses and I have successfully tested them.

But when I want to call the OnError from the Observable, it is not called.

I have this function in a class called ApiCalls.java:

```
public Observable<List<Person>> getPeople(String location)
{
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    APIService service = retrofit.create(APIService .class);

    return service.getPeople(location);
}
```

The function in the Presenter is the following:

```
public void getPeople(final String location) {

    Observable observable= apiCalls.getPeople(location);

     observableResult.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Subscriber<List<Person>>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    Log.w("ON ERROR",e.getMessage());
                    view.showError("An error has occurred");

                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(List<Person> people) {
                    view.refreshPeople(people);
                }
            });
}
```

And then, in the Unit test, I try to do this:

```
   when(apiCalls.getPeople("London"))
            .thenReturn(Observable.error(new HttpException(buildResponse())));

   presenter.getPeople("London");

   verify(peopleView).showError(Mockito.anyString());
```

And the buildResponse:

```
public Response buildResponse()
{
    String json = getJSONError();

    Response response = Response.error(403, ResponseBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/json") ,json));
    return response;
}
```

But, when I test, the following message error appears:

```
Wanted but not invoked:
peopleView.showError(<any string>);
-> at com.lordwater.myapp.PeoplePresenterImpl.testError(PeoplePresenterTest.java:154)
```

EDIT: In the Setup I set the Schedulers to Inmediate:

```
@Before
public void setUp() {

    RxAndroidPlugins.getInstance().registerSchedulersHook(new RxAndroidSchedulersHook() {
        @Override
        public Scheduler getMainThreadScheduler() {
            return Schedulers.immediate();
        }
    });

    presenter = new PeoplePresenterImpl(peopleView);
}

@After
public void tearDown() {
    RxAndroidPlugins.getInstance().reset();
}
```

Comment: Are you using doing anything in your test setup to change the schedulers to immediate?  If not then it's probably a threading issue.

Comment: @Jahnold I think that's the issue; the `.observeOn` might switch the scheduler, and the testing thread does not wait.

Comment: @TassosBassoukos In my edition, in SetUp I set the MainThreadScheduler to Inmediate. If still the problem is the .observeOn, how could I make the testing thread to wait the Observer?

Comment: OK, defenitely the testing is not waiting for the observable to finish. I have put a Thread.sleep and after that it worked. But now I would like to know how can I do to wait for the observable to finish instead of Thread.sleep. I have tried to put ".toBlocking" in the observable in the "when", but the compiler says that "cannot resolve method thenReturn with BlockingObservable")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem in your case is that you didn't override `Schdeulers.io()` in your `RxJavaPlugins` hooks, but just mainThread Scheduler:

```
@Override
public Scheduler getIOScheduler() {
    return Schedulers.immediate();
}
```

As you were saying, when testing real async calls, you must wait to the result otherwise the test will end up with no result, but the network operation itself still happens on a separate thread, thus not blocking the testing thread, and the test finished without results.

Regarding `toBlocking()`, `toBlocking()` is useful when you want to observe the result/s (`onNext()`) , this will convert your `Obesrvable` to `BlockingObservable` which acts somewhat similar to in memory collection, that's means you need to call:

```
 apiCalls.getPeople("London")
    .toBlocking()
    .first();
```

that will block until there is answer, and then you can `assertEquals` this result.
But your scenario is different here, you want to verify that the subscriber acts as expected with `onError()`, meaning you're testing also the subscription.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, now I understand better how does it work. I have tried your solution and defenitevely it worked as I expected.